# Auto-wire third party library in my spring managed component

Tags: java, spring, autowired

I am using a third party library in my application to do some task. They have provided a wrapper that I've added in my project using maven. For using this wrapper we have to give an access key to their client class in order to use it's functionality. For ex:

```
final WeatherApiService was = new WeatherApiServiceImpl(accessKey);
final WeatherApiClient weatherApiClient = new WeatherApiClient(was);
```

What I want is to remove the above code (Since it's kind of Singleton and should be registered in spring context when the application is being started) and do something so that I can just autowire the WeatherApiClient and we are good to go. (wrapper isn't using spring FYI). Below is what I did is in my spring context I registered two beans and put the access-key is web.xml.

> spring-context.xml

```
<bean id="was" class="my.librarypath.WeatherApiService ">
    <constructor-arg type="java.lang.String" value="${accessKeyFromWebXml}"/>
</bean>


<bean id="weatherApiClient" class="my.librarypath.WeatherApiClient">
    <constructor-arg type="my.librarypath.WeatherApiService" value="was"/>
</bean>
```

> my component that will use the third party library

```
@Component("myComponent")
public class MyComponent IComponent {

    @Resource(name = "weatherApiClient") // <--- getting Error here i.e: Couldn't aurtowire, bean should be of String type
    private String weatherApiClient;


     public void myFunction() {
           weatherApiClient.getWeather();
     }


}
```

Can someone confirm if I'm doing it right or is there any best practices options available !?

Comment: instead of `value="was"` use `ref="was"` and your type in your component is wrong as that should be `WeatherApiClient` instead of `String`. So no you aren't doing it right.

Comment: in addition to the error M.Deinum mentioned: you use new WeatherApiServiceImpl(accessKey); in code but you try to create it with <bean id="was" class="my.librarypath.WeatherApiService "> is that correct? If WeatherApiService is an interface this wouldn't work. you should use the impl class as in your code.

Comment: Yes @starbax it is correct. Thanks for your help. It's fixed as said by M. That was the main issue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ther were two issues:

```
<bean id="weatherApiClient" class="my.librarypath.WeatherApiClient">
    <constructor-arg type="my.librarypath.WeatherApiService" value="was"/>
                                                           //  ^---- should be ref
</bean>
```

Secondly, I was using `String` instead of `WeatherApiClient`. MY BAD :/

```
    @Resource(name = "weatherApiClient") 
    private String weatherApiClient;
           //   ^---- this one should have to be WeatherApiClient
```